# Gmail app like fragment navigation with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I want to build navigation exactly the same way like Gmail app. Let me clarify what I mean by that. Gmail app has (at least from the looks of it) 1 hosting activity, many fragments and navigation drawer.

What I want is for the toolbar to behave same as in Gmail app.

When inside list fragment (inbox, important etc.) there is this toolbar: You can see navigation drawer toggle there and it working as expected.

[image]

When navigated to single item fragment theres this toolbar: Note that the back button behaves like the back button should (navigates to previous view). And navigation drawer still can be used by swiping from side.

[image]

I am trying to reproduce this behaviour like this: 
I am inflating toolbar menu for each fragment individually

```
// both inside list and item fragments
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

// inside list fragment
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.list_toolbar, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater)
}

// inside item fragment
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.item_toolbar, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater)
}
```

Now since navigation drawer needs to be used from all fragments. It needs to be placed in hosting activity view (I think). And here's how I initialise it

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // inside hosting activity view
    ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close).apply { 
        addDrawerListener(this)
        syncState()
    }
}
```

This works and I get working navigation drawer. However when I navigate to the item fragment. The back button in toolbar behaves as navigation drawer toggle button showing and hiding drawer instead of navigating back.

PS. this is how I add back button inside item fragment onCreate method

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

So the actual question would be how do I make back button behave like it should instead of toggling navigation drawer?

Comment: so u want when user clicks on toolbar icon he wants to navigate to another activity ..is it right or..what??

Comment: No the navigation should be done only with fragments

Comment: so you want your toolbar to be stay in top when ever transaction

Comment: Yes, isn't that how gmail app works?

Comment: yes but not as you think ..wait I ll show you how

Comment: fragment or activity you want

Comment: fragment if it's possible

Comment: okk..this is simple

Comment: see this it is just simple

Comment: see if this works or not if it doesn't come back here later we will talk about that

Answer (score 1):

**create activity called homeActivity as (example)**

**add this in your xml which is your homeactivity xml**

**FrameLayout as container it help in transaction of Fragment ...and set Framelayout margin top as 50dp done so that the toolbar will stay there when ever you transaction begains**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/too"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:background="@drawable/new_layout"
            >
            <ImageView(icon)
                android:id="@+id/animation_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop = "50dp"
    android:id="@+id/container">
  </FrameLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**use this in home activity for transaction**

```
private void initializeFragment(){

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, homeFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, notificationFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, accountFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, Fragment currentFragment){

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(fragment == homeFragment){

        fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);

    }

    if(fragment == accountFragment){

        fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(notificationFragment);

    }

    if(fragment == notificationFragment){

        fragmentTransaction.hide(homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(accountFragment);

    }
    fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);

    //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: I have everything set up similar as you suggest. I think you misunderstood my question. I have navigation working and everything. But the problem I am facing is toolbar items switching and toolbar back button handling.

Comment: what are you saving you told me that you want toolbar to be in top when ever transaction begains..am I right

Comment: so you don't want toolbar item to be switched